# heroku node app - Application Error

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have an error that I cant really make heads or tails of. https://andrewoneill-io.herokuapp.com/ , here is the build log. Anything insight would help. Code is here https://github.com/Andy93/andrewoneill.io. I create a node app and then connected to my github then did a manual deploy and this happened. Works fine in Localhost

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 8.x...
       Downloading and installing node 8.9.4...
       Using default npm version: 5.6.0
-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules (exists - skipping)
       - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies
       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
       Rebuilding any native modules
       ejs@1.0.0 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/ejs
       express@4.16.2 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/express
       accepts@1.3.4 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/accepts
       mime-types@2.1.17 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/mime-types
       mime-db@1.30.0 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/mime-db
       negotiator@0.6.1 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/negotiator
       array-flatten@1.1.1 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/array-flatten
       body-parser@1.18.2 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/body-parser
       bytes@3.0.0 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/bytes
       content-type@1.0.4 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/content-type
       debug@2.6.9 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/debug
       ms@2.0.0 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/ms
       depd@1.1.2 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/depd
       http-errors@1.6.2 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/http-errors
       depd@1.1.1 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/http-errors/node_modules/depd
       inherits@2.0.3 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/inherits
       setprototypeof@1.0.3 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/http-errors/node_modules/setprototypeof
       statuses@1.3.1 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/statuses
       iconv-lite@0.4.19 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/iconv-lite
       on-finished@2.3.0 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/on-finished
       ee-first@1.1.1 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/ee-first
       qs@6.5.1 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/qs
       raw-body@2.3.2 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/raw-body
       unpipe@1.0.0 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/unpipe
       type-is@1.6.15 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/type-is
       media-typer@0.3.0 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/media-typer
       content-disposition@0.5.2 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/content-disposition
       cookie@0.3.1 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/cookie
       cookie-signature@1.0.6 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/cookie-signature
       encodeurl@1.0.2 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/encodeurl
       escape-html@1.0.3 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/escape-html
       etag@1.8.1 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/etag
       finalhandler@1.1.0 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/finalhandler
       parseurl@1.3.2 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/parseurl
       fresh@0.5.2 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/fresh
       merge-descriptors@1.0.1 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/merge-descriptors
       methods@1.1.2 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/methods
       path-to-regexp@0.1.7 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/path-to-regexp
       proxy-addr@2.0.2 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/proxy-addr
       forwarded@0.1.2 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/forwarded
       ipaddr.js@1.5.2 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/ipaddr.js
       range-parser@1.2.0 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/range-parser
       safe-buffer@5.1.1 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/safe-buffer
       send@0.16.1 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/send
       destroy@1.0.4 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/destroy
       mime@1.4.1 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/mime
       serve-static@1.13.1 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/serve-static
       setprototypeof@1.1.0 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/setprototypeof
       utils-merge@1.0.1 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/utils-merge
       vary@1.1.2 /tmp/build_f0ed54b054098a6e1626383d6dcd3512/Andy93-andrewoneill.io-df80dbe/node_modules/vary
       Installing any new modules (package.json)
       up to date in 0.422s
-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Build succeeded!
 !     This app may not specify any way to start a node process
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 18.5M
-----> Launching...
       Released v4
       https://andrewoneill-io.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

App Log:

```
    2018-01-27T17:01:53.520108+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-01-27T17:01:53.520408+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2018-01-27T17:01:53.520709+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2018-01-27T17:01:53.522307+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! andrewoneill.io@1.0.0 start: `index.js`
2018-01-27T17:01:53.522463+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2018-01-27T17:01:53.522686+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2018-01-27T17:01:53.522905+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the andrewoneill.io@1.0.0 start script.
2018-01-27T17:01:53.530267+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-01-27T17:01:53.523118+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-01-27T17:01:53.530489+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-01-27T17_01_53_524Z-debug.log
2018-01-27T17:01:53.530392+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: Did you add the procfile with `web: node index.js`?

Comment: I got it.. it was in the start script in my package.json file. I wrote 'index.js' instead of 'node index.js'